# MySQL chat system to display last message of sender/receiver AND name of other person

Tags: mysql, sql, database, chat

I'm developing a chat system and the conversation list must display 2 things:

1. last message of whoever sent the message (me a.k.a. current user, or other user)
2. name of **other user**

The part where I'm having issues is the second point. The current query displays the last message of each conversation, but in the cases where me (current user) sent the last message, instead of my name it should be displaying the other user's name.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
    u.id_user AS id,
    i.id_user_from,
    i.id_user_to,
    u.name AS name,
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(i.date_msg) AS date_msg,
    i.message AS msg

    FROM inbox AS i
    INNER JOIN user AS u ON (u.id_user = i.id_user_from OR u.id_user = i.id_user_to)

    WHERE id_msg IN
    (SELECT MAX(id_msg) AS id FROM
    (
        SELECT id_msg, id_user_from AS id_with
        FROM inbox
        WHERE id_user_to = 1

        UNION ALL

        SELECT id_msg, id_user_to AS id_with
        FROM inbox
        WHERE id_user_from = 1) AS t

        GROUP BY id_with
    )

    ORDER BY i.id_msg DESC
```

In this example, I'm **Andufo** (id_user = 1). Here's a [sqlfiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c3a99d/1) if it helps. Thanks!

Comment: For the benefit of all answerers, are you open to changing your database structure for performance/simplicity reasons, or do you want an answer based on your current structure only? Not saying it needs it, but someone else might!

Comment: It appears that the SQL Fiddle link is not working, can you edit your question with the table structure, sample data and then the desired result?

Comment: you want name of from user or to user?

Comment: @halfer yes, im open to change some structures, the only rule is to always have a separated messages table, and a separated users table.

Comment: @AjayPatel always the "to" name. It's very similar to the iMessage, Whatsapp, LINE, etc, inbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this helps

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
    u.id_user AS id,
    i.id_user_from,
    i.id_user_to,
    u.name AS name,
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(i.date_msg) AS date_msg,
    i.message AS msg

    FROM inbox AS i
    INNER JOIN user AS u ON u.id_user = IF(i.id_user_from = 1 /*me*/, i.id_user_to, i.id_user_from)

    WHERE id_msg IN
    (SELECT MAX(id_msg) AS id FROM
    (
        SELECT id_msg, id_user_from AS id_with
        FROM inbox
        WHERE id_user_to = 1

        UNION ALL

        SELECT id_msg, id_user_to AS id_with
        FROM inbox
        WHERE id_user_from = 1) AS t

        GROUP BY id_with
    )
    ORDER BY i.id_msg DESC
```

See [IF mysql operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html)

Comment: @andufo, did you check this?

Comment: Sorry, just came back from vacation, I restart work tomorrow, but I'll try the query in a few mins.

Answer (score 1):

This query will help:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
       u.id_user AS id,
       i.id_user_from,
       i.id_user_to,
       u.name AS name,
       UNIX_TIMESTAMP(i.date_msg) AS date_msg,
       i.message AS msg
    FROM inbox AS i,
         user  AS u,
         (SELECT MAX(id_msg) AS id_max,
                 id_with
              FROM (
                    SELECT id_msg,
                           id_user_from AS id_with
                        FROM inbox
                        WHERE id_user_to = 1
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT id_msg,
                           id_user_to
                        FROM inbox
                        WHERE id_user_from = 1
                   ) AS t
              GROUP BY id_with) AS m
    WHERE i.id_msg  = m.id_max
      AND u.id_user = m.id_with
    ORDER BY i.id_msg DESC
```